# Clic in risc-v for interrupt handler

Tags: c, interrupt, riscv

i am implementing a driver for i2c communication device on a platform that uses the ris-v and click interrupt. However, it happens that the driver enters the interrupt handler twice, even if in reality I received only one interrupt, the one I have seen from the waveforms. The interrupt is of type eot, end of transmission, and is called when a specific command is sent. When I send the eot command, an interrupt is sent at the hardware level. Do any of you know why?

Comment: Are you saying that for every one signal, the interrupt handler triggers twice?

Comment: @Mode77, Yes even if I have only one interrupt signal, I have the interrupt handler execution twice.

Comment: Inside the interrupt handler, are you disabling interrupts? On some architectures, you have to do this to prevent interrupts from interrupting the handler.

Comment: @ Mode77, even disabling interrupt in the interrupt handler I still have this problem.

Comment: You say that the interrupt is triggered on EOT when a certain command is sent. Can you give more detail in your post about this command?

Comment: When I send the eot command, an interrupt is sent at the hardware level.

Comment: Can't you ignore that interrupt, by detecting it and doing nothing in the interrupt handler?

Comment: @ErikEidt, no because the interrupt is used to release a task.

Comment: Increment an atomic counter as you send the EOT, and decrement in the handler, to see if you should release the task?